# Issue with populating a listbox with an already existing array

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

```
    struct process
    {
        public int Proc_Id;
        public int Proc_BurstTime;
        public int Proc_Priority;
    };

    readonly process[] ProcessList = new process[]
    {
        new process{ Proc_Id = 1, Proc_BurstTime = 3000, Proc_Priority = 1},
        new process{ Proc_Id = 2, Proc_BurstTime = 5000, Proc_Priority = 2},
        new process{ Proc_Id = 3, Proc_BurstTime = 1000, Proc_Priority = 3},
        new process{ Proc_Id = 4, Proc_BurstTime = 10000, Proc_Priority = 4}
    };

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initial_ProcessList.Items.AddRange(ProcessList);
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)' has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OS450_Proj1.Form1.process[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'
```

I understand that it looks like it doesn't like that kind of array, but is there anything can do to populate the listbox?  If it is also because there's no string or anything to "print" onto the list, do I need to add a string value to the struct and initialize it for all the values in the array (ProcessList)?  If so, how can I go about that when adding to the listbox?

Comment: You may have to convert it to a list via a .ToList() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can't cast somearray to  `object[]`. `ListBox.Items.AddRange` requires object array to be passed as parameter.

Try this

```
initial_ProcessList.Items.AddRange(ProcessList.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

or this

```
object[] ProcessList = new object[]
{
    new process{ Proc_Id = 1, Proc_BurstTime = 3000, Proc_Priority = 1},
    new process{ Proc_Id = 2, Proc_BurstTime = 5000, Proc_Priority = 2},
    new process{ Proc_Id = 3, Proc_BurstTime = 1000, Proc_Priority = 3},
    new process{ Proc_Id = 4, Proc_BurstTime = 10000, Proc_Priority = 4}
};
```

Or just loop and add

```
foreach (var p in ProcessList)
{
    initial_ProcessList.Items.Add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First the error, If the method is expecting a `object[]` it can't take a `process[]` for that. Now if you try something like:

```
initial_ProcessList.Items.AddRange(ProcessList.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

The error would go away but the `ListBox` items would appear like:

```
WindowForm.ApplicationName.process1
WindowForm.ApplicationName.process1
.....
```

Which is the default `ToString()` implementation. So your actual problem is displaying those records in the `ListBox`. You have to override `ToString` method. like:

```
struct process
{
    public int Proc_Id;
    public int Proc_BurstTime;
    public int Proc_Priority;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Proc_Id, Proc_BurstTime, Proc_Priority);
    }
};
```

Later it would even more simpler if use the `DataSource` Property instead of adding an object array so simply do:

```
initial_ProcessList.DataSource = ProcessList;
```

This would show the result as:

[image]

You can also set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` property of your `ListBox` but it would require your structure to have properties, instead of fields. So you have to modify your `struct` as:

```
struct process
{
    public int Proc_Id { get; set; }
    public int Proc_BurstTime { get; set; } //auto implemented properties
    public int Proc_Priority;
```

};

And then:

```
initial_ProcessList.ValueMember = "Proc_Id";
initial_ProcessList.DisplayMember = "Proc_BurstTime";
initial_ProcessList.DataSource = ProcessList;
```

This would show only `Proc_BurstTime`, and on selection you will get the value of related `Proc_Id`